# Optimize order in which msbuild builds projects

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Im investigating how to optimize clean build of about 3000 fsharp projects on our TeamCity. The hierarchy is quite deep, but nothing out of ordinary. On perfmon that teamcity provides i can see that two times in the middle of the build only 2 cores are occupied,out of 36.
I suspect all other cores are waiting for built dependencies.
Using vs 2017, what are best ways to check what projects are bottlenecks and should be split or optimized?
How can i hint msbuild that those projects and their dependencies should be built in the first place?

Comment: You might want to start by enabling additional MSBuild logging, such as enabling the PerformanceSummary and/or detailedSummary. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference

Comment: We are including those extra details but they dont show where the bottleneck can be, ir i dont know what to look for - they are big in our case. I also added timestamp on every event of console logger, but its messy, out of order.

Comment: I am not aware of any tool that makes it super straightforward. You could try the [MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) or the [Project System Tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProjectSystemTools&ssr=false#overview) for Visual Studio, which both provide GUIs for inspecting/debugging builds.